# The group $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ .

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

I am looking for a detailed study of the group $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, its topology, subgroups, on any point of view (algebraic, complex or real Lie group theory, etc.). I am interested in any good survey or book able to enlight me on this group !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the book exactly on $Sl(n,\mathbb{C})$ but you can find some information in different books on Classical groups:

There is a book of Dieudonne Geometry of classical groups, but I am not sure whether it is available in English.

A book of Hermann Weyl The Classical Groups: Their Invariants and Representations discusses representation theory in detail (you can also read any modern book on representations of semisimple groups)

If you are interested in topology note, that topologically $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ is a product of $SU(n)$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n^2-1}$. So you are intereted in the topology of $SU(n)$ (and that is what you need to search for).

Hope some of these helps.

Comment: I am familiar with the classical results. But I am going to take a look on the book of Dieudonné, thank you very much.

Comment: So I have taken a look at Dieudonné's book. I focuses to much on the general case, where $K$ is an unspecified field. The funny thing is he doesn't require the product law to be commutative, which I knew to be an old French specificity, but which I had never seen written. Actually, I am more interested in the Lie group structure, this question echoes the one I asked two days ago : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646183/closed-subgroups-of-mathrmsl2-mathbbc

Comment: You know the general theory of "real forms"? I believe it answers the Lie group structure question :)
For that question you asked: I am quite sure that I have seen the answer in some book on hyperbolic geometry (maybe in Kapovich Hyberbolic manifolds and discrete groups?) It is just quite a big book, and I didn't have time to look through it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the result is in Kapovich's book, p.69.