# When does the closure of a free subgroup of $\mathsf{SL}(2;\mathbb{C})$ equal $\mathsf{SL}(2;\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, free-groups

Let $A \subset \mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$ be a finite set of matrices. Consider the set $$S = \overline{\langle A \rangle},$$ where we take the closure in $\mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$, and where $\langle A \rangle$ denotes the free group of $A$.

Clearly $S$ is a group, and by construction $S$ is closed in $\mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$. Therefore, by Cartan's closed subgroup theorem, it must be the case that $S$ is a Lie subgroup of $\mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$. I am interested in understanding what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ for it to be the case that, in fact, $S = \mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$?

It is easy to come up with a few concrete conditions for insufficiency: for instance, if all the elements of $A$ are mutually commuting, or if $A \subset \mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{R})$, or if $A \subset \mathsf{SU}(2)$. But I am interested in more systematically characterizing when $S$ equals $\mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$.

Any thoughts or references are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: It is essentially the dichotomy: Either your subgroup is discrete or it is dense in $SL(2,C)$. (There are some exceptions to this which are easy to describe, since the list of proper closed subgroups of $SL(2,C)$ is rather short.) What books have you read about discrete subgroups of $SL(2,C)$?

Comment: I haven't read any books particularly about discrete subgroups of SL(2, C). I have been going through Brian Hall's text "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations," and this question occurred to me. Are there some references you could suggest for proper closed subgroups of $SL(2; \mathbb{C})$ and/or discrete subgroups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the list of closed connected subgroups of
$SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ is not very long, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646183/list-of-connected-lie-subgroups-of-mathrmsl2-mathbbc/650285#650285). From that, you conclude that a subgroup $\Gamma< SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ is either *virtually solvable* (i.e. contains a solvable subgroup of finite index), or is discrete, or is dense in $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$  or its closure equals a conjugate of $SU(2)$ or $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ or contains $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ as an index 2 subgroup.

Thus, effectively, you are asking for necessary and sufficient conditions for discreteness of a finitely generated subgroup of $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$. There is one standard necessary condition for discreteness of 2-generated subgroups $\Gamma$ which are not virtually solvable, called the **[Jorgensen Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B8rgensen%27s_inequality)**:
$$
{\displaystyle \left|\operatorname {Tr} (A)^{2}-4\right|+\left|\operatorname {Tr} \left(ABA^{-1}B^{-1}\right)-2\right|\geq 1.\,}
$$
Here are $A, B$ are generators of $\Gamma$. From this, one deduces the following:

> Suppose that a subgroup $\Gamma< SL(2, {\mathbb C})$ is not virtually solvable. Then $\Gamma$ is discrete if and only if any pair of elements $A, B\in \Gamma$ either generates a virtually solvable subgroup or satisfies the above inequality.

(I am replacing your condition that $\Gamma$ is free by the weaker condition that $\Gamma$ is not virtually solvable.) There are other conditions which are either necessary or sufficient for discreteness, but the one above is the most concise. See also the discussion in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109967/algorithm-to-test-for-discrete-or-quasi-fuchsian-subgroups-of-psl2-c/223677#223677) Mathoverflow question.

For some recent work on discreteness conditions see

*Klimenko, Elena; Kopteva, Natalia*, [**A two-dimensional slice through the parameter space of two-generator Kleinian groups**](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218196718400076), Int. J. Algebra Comput. 28, No. 8, 1535-1564 (2018). [ZBL1412.30132](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1412.30132).

and references therein.

If you want to read more about discrete subgroups of $SL(2, {\mathbb C})$, there are many books to choose from, for instance,

*Beardon, Alan F.*, [**The geometry of discrete groups**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382526), Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 91. New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XII, 337 p. (1983). [ZBL0528.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0528.30001).

*Matsuzaki, Katsuhiko; Taniguchi, Masahiko*, Hyperbolic manifolds and Kleinian groups, Oxford Mathematical Monographs. Oxford: Clarendon Press. ix, 253 p. (1998). [ZBL0892.30035](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0892.30035).

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: quick follow up question. It seems in your answer, that there is another implicit dichotomy being drawn, that is not immediately clear to me. Namely, your answer seems to suggest that for any closed subgroup $\Gamma < \mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{C})$, it is either the case that $\Gamma$ is connected, or $\Gamma$ is virtually solvable/discrete.  Am I understanding this correctly, and if so, why must this be the case?

Comment: @cdkaram: almost. There is one more case, which is an index 2 extension of $SL(2,R)$. It just comes out of a classification, there is no profound reason for this.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. Is there a reference you can point me to where this classification is worked out that you know of?

Comment: @cdkaram: you can start by reading my linked answer.

Comment: I've been going through the linked answer, but I think where I am stuck right now is understanding the dichotomy between the connected and disconnected cases. In particular, why is it the case that if a subgroup $\overline{\Gamma} < \mathsf{SL}(2;\mathbb{C})$ is disconnected, then either $\Gamma$ is virtually solvable, $\Gamma$ is discrete, or $\Gamma$ contains $\mathsf{SL}(2; \mathbb{R})$ as an index 2 subgroup?

Comment: @cdkaram: Can you prove that if a subgroup of $SL(2,C)$ contains $SU(2)$ as a normal subgroup then it equals $SU(2)$?

Comment: I think I can see how to prove it by "brute force" just by explicitly writing out 2x2 matrices and solving the conditions on the conjugating elements. I don't know if there is a more sophisticated way of showing this using the structure of the Lie groups themselves?

Comment: Geometric way is to observe that SU(2) fixes unique point in the hyperbolic 3-space, which then must be fixed by the normalizer as well. Algebraic is to note that SU(2) has unique, up to scaling, invariant hermitian form on $C^2$ which then has to be invariant under the normalizer.

Comment: Do you see how to play the same "unique fixed point" game with other types of subgroups?

Comment: I don't think so, I am not so familiar with algebraic geometry (I don't really understand what it means that $SU(2)$ fixes a unique point in the hyperbolic 3-space).

Comment: @cdkaram: Do you know that linear fractional transformations act isometrically on hyperbolic 3-space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152363/discussion-between-cdkaram-and-moishe-kohan).